# Is there a nicer idiom for "repeat N times" than "for _" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is quite simple; is there a nicer way to repeat a block of code

```
for _ in range(N):
    stuff = 10
    thing = True
    a_task(stuff, thing)
    ...
```

or to create a list of N objects of the same class like `a_list = [AnObject() for _ in range(N)]` but without ugly `for _ in range(N)`?

---

Something like

```
with repeat(50):
    ...
```

would be nice for the block case but I guess it's not possible to achieve it with context managers.

Also note that `a_list = [AnObject()] * N` is not an answer for the second case since it copies references.

---

Any nice alternative for the ugly `for _` in both cases?

Comment: No, that's the common idiom.

Comment: Ugly is subjective, I personally find it okay. Do you have a particular construct in mind, maybe from another language?

Comment: *is there a nicer way to repeat a block of code*  -  a function?

Comment: Remember the Zen of Python. *There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it. Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.* Using the common idiom means people will recognize your code's intent and behavior at a glance. Resist the impulse to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Joel Spolsky's parallel -- with respect to it taking time and skill to learn to recognize what is and is not a clean bakery, just as it takes time and skill to get a practiced eye as to what is and is not good code -- in the essay at https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/ is apropos.

Comment: Python developers have put more effort into developing iterable data structures (lists, tuples, dict, generators) and less on fancy iteration syntax.  The `for` loop and comprehensions are usually enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a decorator that takes an argument indicating the number of loops:

```
@loop(40)
def my_function:
    pass
```

That said, the list comprehension syntax is idiomatic. Also, I don't know why you are using '_' for this, that just makes it uglier, IMHO

Comment: you *could* do a lot of things, but this would be over-engineering it to the point of being obscurantist. Using a single underscore is just a convention to indicate a 'throwaway' variable (we don't actually use it).

Comment: Not disagreeing, just answering the question. Never said it was good practice. Also, I'm aware of the usage of an underscore as a throwaway, but this person asked about making it look nicer, and using an actual variable name would look nicer, IMHO